# LineChart - Is it possible to only show xAxis labels when there is a data point?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart to get a line chart. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image: example]

Where xAxis labels appear only there's a data point and points are equidistant.

My xAxis configuration is like this at this moment:

```kotlin
xAxis.apply {
    position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    granularity = 7f
    isGranularityEnabled = true
    setDrawGridLines(false)
    setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)
    setLabelCount(orders.size, true)
    labelRotationAngle = 315f
    setCenterAxisLabels(true)
    valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            return Instant
                .ofEpochMilli(value.toLong())
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate()
                .format(formatter)
                .toString()

        }
    }
}

Collections.sort(entry, EntryXComparator())
```

The chart I'm getting is this

[image: myChart]

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try setting maximum and minimum values to the axis (.axisMaximum/.axisMinimum) by calculating the max and minimum values to be plotted. I think then the graph will adjust automatically I believe. Worth a try :)

Comment: You said "xAxis labels appear only there's a data point and points are equidistant." but in your second image the points are not equidistant - the gap between points varies. Do you want a label at each point, or evenly spaced labels? Can you please include a sample data-set in your question so that someone can reproduce the behavior you are seeing?